# Breadth-first traversal of a tree of slider puzzle configurations java

Tags: java, tree, breadth-first-search, sliding-tile-puzzle

I need help with my PuzzleSolver class. I get a notice saying

> Note: SliderPuzzleSolver.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

I don't understand what this means and also when I run my tester I get this

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
> Index 0 out of bounds for length 0    at
> SPS_Tester.main(SPS_Tester.java:23)

If anyone would have some guesses about any of these please shoot them my way.

```
public class SliderPuzzleSolver {
   
   /* Returns a String encoding a shortest sequence of moves leading from
   ** the given starting configuration to the standard goal configuration,
   ** or null if there is no such sequence.
   ** pre: !start.equals( the standard goal configuration )
   */
   public static String solution(SliderPuzzleConfig start) {
      int numRows = start.numRows();
      int numCols = start.numColumns();
      SliderPuzzleConfig standardGoal = new SliderPuzzleConfig(numRows, numCols);
      return solution(start, standardGoal);
   } 
   public static String solution(SliderPuzzleConfig start,
                                 SliderPuzzleConfig goal) {
      SliderPuzzleSolverNode treeNode = new SliderPuzzleSolverNode(start, "");     
      QueueViaLink1<SliderPuzzleSolverNode> toBeExplored = new QueueViaLink1();
      toBeExplored.enqueue(treeNode);
      while (!toBeExplored.isEmpty()) {
         treeNode = toBeExplored.dequeue();
         SliderPuzzleConfig config = treeNode.config;
         char[] direction = { 'U', 'D', 'L', 'R' };
         for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            if(config.canMove(direction[i])) {
               SliderPuzzleConfig newConfig = config.clone();
               newConfig.move(direction[i]);
               if(newConfig != goal) {   //newConfig was not discovered earlier
                  String moveSeq = treeNode.moveSeq + direction;
                  SliderPuzzleSolverNode newTreeNode = new SliderPuzzleSolverNode(newConfig, moveSeq);
                  toBeExplored.enqueue(newTreeNode);
                  if (newConfig == goal) {
                     return moveSeq;
                  }
               } 
            }
         }
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```

```
public class SPS_Tester {

   /* Provided with command line arguments (or what jGrasp refers to as
   ** "run arguments") indicating the dimensions of a puzzle, a seed
   ** for a pseudo-random number generator, and a number of pseudo-random
   ** moves to make --starting with the standard goal configuration-- to
   ** obtain an initial configuration, this method uses the solution()
   ** method in the SliderPuzzleSolver class to find a minimum-length
   ** sequence of moves that transforms that initial configuration into
   ** the standard goal configuration.  This method then displays the
   ** configurations along that path of moves.
   */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int numRows = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      int numCols = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      int seed = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
      Random rand = new Random(seed);
      int numMoves = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

      SliderPuzzleConfig start = 
         new SliderPuzzleConfig(numRows, numCols, rand, numMoves); 

      System.out.println("Starting configuration is");
      start.display();
      System.out.println();

      String solution = SliderPuzzleSolver.solution(start);
      if (solution == null) {
         System.out.println("No solution was found.");
      }
      else {
         System.out.printf("Path of length %d found:\n\n", solution.length());
         displayPath(start, solution);
      }

      System.out.println("\nGoodbye.");
   }

   /* Displays the sequence of configurations starting with the one 
   ** given and proceeding according to the given sequence of moves.
   */
   public static void displayPath(SliderPuzzleConfig config, String moveSeq) {
      SliderPuzzleConfig spc = config.clone();
      spc.display();
      for (int i = 0; i != moveSeq.length(); i++) {
         char dir = moveSeq.charAt(i);
         spc.move(dir);
         System.out.printf("\nAfter moving %c:\n", dir);
         spc.display();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: SliderPuzzleSolver.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations

It means you are not using a generic type somewhere that you could or should. This is just a warning. It looks like the only place is
`QueueViaLink1<SliderPuzzleSolverNode> toBeExplored = new QueueViaLink1();`
It should be `new QueViaLink1<SliderPuzzleSolverNode>()` or in recent versions of Java you can also use `newQueViaLink1<>()` . You can use the compiler settings in jGRASP, or whatever IDE you're using if it's not that, to add the suggested compiler flag if you want the specific error messages.

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for
> length 0

It appears you are not passing any command line arguments. Your program should test the length of args[] before accessing the elements, and fail with an error message if there are not enough.